# Access component prop from directive parameter

Tags: vuejs2, vue-directives

I have a component (C) and a parent component (P).
From P want to define a C component with a specific prop, then from a vue directive in the C component i want to use that prop value.

Declaration in the parent component:

```
<WindowContainer winTitle="windows.languageSelection.headerTitle"></WindowContainer>
```

Then in the Child component i want to access thi prop

```
div id="header" v-localize="{i: '{{winTitle}}'}"></div>
```

How do i access the winTitle prop value?

Answer (score 0):

you use wrong grammer,{{}} should be used between tag,not in the tags attributes,so,you can try this,it probably works

```
div id="header" v-localize="{i: winTitle}"></div>
```